# Textblock above radiobutton custom style

Tags: silverlight, xaml, embedded

I am using Silverlight for embedded windows  and i have  a simple radiobutton style

```
<Style TargetType="RadioButton" x:Key="SettingsTab">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="95"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <Image x:Name="Ozadje1" Source="settings_backgroun.png"/>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now i want to put 2 textblock above that like you can see on 2nd image.

this is the image i use in style:
[image: Settings_backgroun.png]

[image: what i want]

Because i am new to silverlight i have a few problems with this, so i hope someone can point me in right direction.

Please keep in mind that silverlight for embedded windows is Silverlight 3 without some components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're doing is adding the TextBlock's than this should accomplish it, (as hoping that Embedded Windows will allow it.)

```
<Style TargetType="RadioButton" x:Key="SettingsTab">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="95"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <Image x:Name="Ozadje1" Source="settings_backgroun.png"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="LIM" Foreground="Orange" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="3.5mA" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```